# java mongodb - get array length without downloading all data

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I'm using mongodb to store data for my java program and I have a collection with an array field that has a lot of things in it but i want only to get the length, without all the other data.

Now i'm using this to get it:

```
((UUID[])document.get("customers")).length
```

How can I make this not to download all the array?

A possible answer is to create an int that counts the pushes and the pulls of the array but it's not the cleanest method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where you can use the **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operator in your pipeline, this counts and returns the total the number of items in an array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "customer_count": { "$size": "$customers" }
         }
    }
]);
```

where the Java equivalent:

```
DBObject projectFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", 0);
projectFields.put("customer_count", new BasicDBObject( "$size", "$customers" ));
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", projectFields);

AggregationOutput output = db.getCollection("collectionName").aggregate(project);

System.out.println("\n" + output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB's Aggregation Framework to get the size of the array. For example, given the following document structure:

```
> db.macross.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "SDF1",
    "crew" : [
            "Rick",
            "Minmay",
            "Roy",
            "Max",
            "Misa",
            "Milia"
    ]
}
```

get the size of the array

```
> db.macross.aggregate( 
    { $match: { _id: "SDF1" } }, 
    { $unwind: "$crew" }, 
    { $group: { _id: "", count: { $sum: 1 } } }, 
    { $project: { _id: 0, count: 1 } }
)
{ "count" : 6 }
```

More detailed and interesting examples are available in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#example).

Comment: Hey @blimpyacht what if the values in _id is dynamic. I actually have to find the size of nested array but there are around 120k documents in my collection and for each collection I have to perform this action. 
Can you please help me by giving suggestions